# in a vuejs app, css background-image inserts an unwanted space in file url

Tags: css, vue.js

Here is the element:

```
<section class="company-intro" v-bind:style='[{ backgroundImage :backgroundImage }]'>
```

And in the script :

```
beforeMount(){
    this.backgroundImage= 'url(' + (this.companyInfo.main_photo) + ')';
    alert(this.backgroundImage)
},
```

the alert returns

> url(http:\files.balatar.inpin.co\companies/main_photos/aGC5IZuGKFgTN516xxzfXgjH0BY0DPiVsmf6X0AC.jpeg)

But the actual background-image is served like below in the browser:

> background-image: url(http:\files.balatar.inpin.co\c ompanies/main_photos/aGC5IZuGKFgTN516xxzfXgjH0BY0DPiVsmf6X0AC.jpeg

Which seems to put an extra character in the url thus the browser requests below url:

> http://localhost:8080/files.balatar.inpin.co%0Companies/main_photos/aGC5IZuGKFgTN516xxzfXgjH0BY0DPiVsmf6X0AC.jpeg

And fails to download the image. why do i see this strange behavior?

Comment: Should be http:// not http:\

Comment: slashes (`/`) should not be backslashes (\\) in a URL